# Heroku : how to have a wordpress running on /blog?

Tags: nginx, heroku, cloudflare

We have a rails app on heroku on https://www.example.com

We need a wordpress (not running on heroku) available on https://www.example.com/blog (the SEO team prefer /blog than blog.example.com)

The Heroku team told me it is not possible to config the heroku router, and I don't want the request to be treated by my Rails app, How can I do this?

- I think it is definitely not possible at the DNS level?
- Maybe put something in front of Heroku like Cloudflare? that would 'intercept' all the requests with `/blog`?
- Maybe have kind of a reverse proxy inside the `heroku-buildpack` like `heroku-buildpack-nginx` that would 'intercept' all the requests with `/blog`?